# flat php connects to database but Laravel not

Tags: php, mysql, database, laravel

Let's start by loging in the website...the error log was:

> local.ERROR: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user
>   'cp35161_xxx'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from
>   `users` limit 1) {"exception":"[object]
>   (Illuminate\Database\QueryException(code: 1045): SQLSTATE[HY000]
>   [1045] Access denied for user 'cp35161_xxx'@'127.0.0.1' (using
>   password: YES) (SQL: select * from `users` limit 1) at
>   /home/cp35161/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php:664,
>   PDOException(code: 1045): SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for
>   user 'cp35161_xxx'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES) at
>   /home/cp35161/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php:70)

So I entered the code below in `/public/index.php`:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost; dbname=cp35161_xxx", "cp35161_yyy", "zzz");
$a = $conn->query("select * from users")->fetchAll();
print_r($a);
die;
```

This one printed out the data. Where the problem is from?

My `.env` file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=cp35161_xxx
DB_USERNAME=cp35161_yyy
DB_PASSWORD=zzz
```

My `/config/database.php` file:

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

'mysql' => [
    'driver' => 'mysql',
    'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
    'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
    'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
    'prefix' => '',
    'prefix_indexes' => false,
    'strict' => false,
    'engine' => null,
],
```

Comment: User `cp35161_xxx` ?? That seems to be your dbname, right? Did you have them swapped before? Could try running `php artisan config:clear` to reread the config/env variables.

Comment: Have you tried with 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost?

Comment: I have censored db_name and user :))) Because it is shared host I can't access ssh and terminal to run `php artisan`. I tried that `127.0.0.1` but no result.

Comment: I fixed it by going to `/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php` on line 70 and set the pdo params statically :)) Of course it is wrong way but I didn't know how to clear cache. I think it couldn't get the env constants. because anywhere I had used `env()` didn't work. So I set statically. Is it possible to run command on shared host in order to run `php artisan` command to overcome this issue?